# What is $k_{\text{max}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

> If
>
> $[1-\cos x][1 - \cos 2x][1 - \cos 3x] = k\ ; 0º < x < 90º$
>
> Find $k_{\text{max}}$

I have no idea how to solve this

I've got  $8\left[\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\times\sin x \times \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)\right]^2 = k$

Help me please ...
Thank you to all.

Comment: Can you use calculus techniques to find the local maxima of the function on the left hand side?

Comment: Maximum value seems to be $\frac{2437+340\sqrt{10}}{1458}$ according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize%5B%281-cos+%28x%29%29%281-cos%282*x%29%29%281-cos%283*x%29%29%5D)

Answer (score 3):

$$\Big(2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}\sin x\sin\dfrac{3x}{2}\Big)^2=\sin^2 x\Big(\cos x-\cos 2x\Big)^2=(1-\cos^2x)\Big(-2\cos^2x+\cos x+1\Big)^2$$ Let $$f(t)=(1-t^2)(2t^2-t-1)^2=(1-t)^3(1+t)(1+2t)^2$$ where $t\in[0,1]$ Try to find the maximum of $f.$ I think that would be enough.

Comment: This makes the problem very simple ! Thank you.

Comment: $$t=-\frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{(-2 - \sqrt{10})}{6}, \frac{(-2+\sqrt{10})}{6}$$ are the zeros of derivative of $f.$

Comment: Fix your typo's in the comment.

Comment: I had the answer. I just wanted to thank your for the nice approach of the solution. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you. I fixed them. I really like to see your answer.

Comment: I made it much more complex. Computing the derivative of the function after replacing $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(3x)$ by the expressions as functions of $\cos(x)$. Then, ugly trigonometric manipulations. Your is really nice and simple.